# Syntax of H.264 SPS/PPS in SIP/SDP offer

Tags: video, sip, h.264, rtp, sdp

According to RFC 6184:

> Annex B of H.264 defines an encapsulation    process to transmit such
>   NALUs over bytestream-oriented networks.  In    the scope of this
>   memo, Annex B is not relevant.

I see a lot of examplex, including in RFC6236, of SPS/PPS like this

```
a=fmtp:99 packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e011; \
      sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LgC5ZUCg/I,aM4BrFSAa
```

However, according to H.264, Annex B, there should be no comma, and a preamble must be added to the beginning of both SPS and PPS (and after that SPS/PPS is converted to base 64).

So I don't understand what is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comma should be there. prefix is for MPEG-2 only.

Answer (score 1):

The comma separates SPS and PPS. They are two separate units (in Annex B format).

Answer (score 1):

seperate the sps and the pps to two byte arrays.
convert them to base 64.
add the prefix '001' to each one.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is above and these are specification references:

[RFC 3984](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt):

> sprop-parameter-sets:
>
> This parameter MAY be used to convey
>                           any sequence and picture parameter set NAL
>                           units (herein referred to as the initial
>                           parameter set NAL units) that MUST precede any
>                           other NAL units in decoding order.  The
>                           parameter MUST NOT be used to indicate codec
>                           capability in any capability exchange
>                           procedure.  The value of the parameter is the
>                           base64 [6] representation of the initial
>                           parameter set **NAL units as specified in
>                           sections 7.3.2.1 and 7.3.2.2 of [1]**.  The
>                           parameter sets are conveyed in decoding order,
>                           and no framing of the parameter set NAL units
>                           takes place.  **A comma is used to separate any
>                           pair of parameter sets in the list.**  Note that
>                           the number of bytes in a parameter set NAL unit
>                           is typically less than 10, but a picture
>                           parameter set NAL unit can contain several
>                           hundreds of bytes.

Where [1] above is H.264 spec reference, and its 7.3.2.1 and 7.3.2.2 sections define bitstream **without** start code prefixes.

> 7.3.2 Raw byte sequence payloads and RBSP trailing bits syntax
>   7.3.2.1 Sequence parameter set RBSP syntax
>   7.3.2.2 Picture parameter set RBSP syntax