# ffmpeg .264 video conversion to jpg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I googled it but I could not find any proper answer. So I am posting here.

I am trying to convert images from IP camera videos which are stored in .264 format. I gave this command to convert:

```
ffmpeg -i P1234_5665.264 -an -ss 2 -s 1280x720 test1.jpg
```

It does not convert and it gives error:

```
[h264 @ 00863fc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00863fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00863fc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 00863fc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00863fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00863fc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 00863fc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00863fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00863fc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 00863fc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00863fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00863fc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 00863fc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00863fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00863fc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 00863fc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00863fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00863fc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 00863fc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00863fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00863fc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 00863fc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00863fc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00863fc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0081f740] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 0081f740] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (Mai
n), none(progressive)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, h264, from 'P1234_5665.264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), none(progressive), 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tb
n, 50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid data found when proc
essing input
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your .264 file is missing a picture parameter set (PPS) at the beginning. PPS is a special H.264 [NAL unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Abstraction_Layer) ("packet") that contains necessary information to decode the following packets.

You should check how the .264 file is created.  In many H.264 streams the PPS (and SPS, "sequence parameter set") are transmitted before every I-frame.  But in some also not, eg. an IP camera might only send this information as an [RTSP DESCRIBE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol#Protocol_directives) reply in the [SDP data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606072/syntax-of-h-264-sps-pps-in-sip-sdp-offer).